# APK building failed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I've been trying to build an apk for my app but its failing and I don't understand why
this is what is shwoing

[image]

i tried to build using this command that was given to me in comments

```
flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons
```

but its showing me this new error now

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this when build your apk `--no-tree-shake-icons`

Comment: while its bulding or after or before?

Comment: use this command when building apk `flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons`

Comment: tried it but showed new problem. please see the post i updated it

Comment: Okay, try to increase your minSdkVersion (Usually I use 21 for Android 5.0), or do you intend to target device with minSdkVer 16?

Comment: do i run something in terminal to do so ?

Comment: No, just go to android/app/build.gradle, and find minSdkVersion

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for errors that seem odd like this, running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` in the terminal helps.

Comment: did not work T_T